# Expand, Multiply a Channelfield

Tags: channel-entries, channel-fields

Does anybody know a Add-on or something like that which can do the following:

I'd like to have, in my Publish-form an editable field; for instance I have a date field (LowEvent) which adds a date to my entry for an event. But some of my entries have several separated dates.

I'd like to have some kind of a 'Plus/add icon' which can create a new date field on the fly in my Publish form, sort of speak.

Any Ideas??

Best regards Dave

Comment: Why not a grid field? Isn't LowEvents compatible?

Comment: I'd also say use Grid or Matrix.